# Combining integers and strings when asking for input?

Tags: string

This is a very basic question as I am new to computer programming but I am having problems. The question is asking me to write in Python 3 an equation for area of a rectangle that allows the user to input the width and length in square feet and output the answer in square feet. This is what I've tried:

```
width = int(input("What is the width of the rectangle?")
        10 ft^2
length = int(input("What is the length of the rectangle?")
        5 ft^2
area = str(length*width("feet squared.")
```

but I get errors when even trying to input an integer with "feet squared" attached to it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: the length and width should be in feet, just enter a number not the `ft^2`, you could change `int(...)` to `parseInt(...)`

Comment: ...input two length values in square feet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the `area` assigment part to,

```
area = str(length*width) + " feet squared."
```

That is you must use the string concatenation operator `+` here.

or

```
area = "{0} feet squared.".format(length*width)
```

Comment: The second modification for the area assignment 'area = "{0} feet squared.".format(length*width)' worked but the first one did not, any reasoning why? Also your help was greatly appreciated.

Comment: first one works for me.  Give credits to the answerer by clicking the accept button.

Answer (score 0):

Example answer using numbers following rules stated in question:

```
width = input("What is the width of the rectangle?"
# What is the width of the rectangle? 10
length = input("What is the length of the rectangle?")
# What is the width of the rectangle? 5
area = "{0} feet squared.".format(length*width)
print(area)
# 50 feet squared.
```